# How to convert pixels into meters in a 2D world?

Tags: java, libgdx

First of all I'm not using box2d which means I cannot just invent a number and make it the value of ppm. What I'm trying to do is something like [this](http://www.design-simulation.com/IP/simulationlibrary/flashsimulations/AirResistance01.swf), but the user can set the altitude of the object. When I implemented gravity without air resistance the time it took to hit the ground was around 1.4 seconds, and the starting altitude of my object/sprite was around 590 pixels. Then I used a calculator to calculate the altitude into meters, and it was around 9.6m (if the object fell for 1.4 seconds). But then I don't know how to calculate the amount of pixels required for each meter, it is more confusing since that the velocity y of the object increases by 9.8 pixels per second because there is no air resistance. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't make it so hard for yourself by using those useless and imaginary "pixels" units. See also: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Answer (score 0):

590px/9.6m = 61.458 pixels to a meter. Round as you would prefer.

Comment: I did that but doesn't work, I also forgot to mention that the ground start at 77 pixel because it's 77 in height. So what I did (590 -77) / 9.6 and at 1 meter the object overlap the ground.

Comment: @StormAsdg are the 513 pixels a fixed amount? Or do the number of pixels change when the user changes the height?

Comment: No it's not fixed, at around 590 or 660 pexels in height (I don't exactly remember) takes 1.4 second for the object to hit the ground, and if an object fell for 1.4sec it means it was dropped at around 9.6m. Yes the user can change the altitude

Comment: So if I get this right, the user sets height _in_ _pixels_ then drops it. Then using the amount time it takes to fall the height _in_ _meters_ is calculated?

Comment: Yes and no, the user set the height in meters then what I am suppose to do is //userInputMeter * ppm. That 1.4sec is the time it takes for an object to hit the ground (if the object height is 660) and I am only using it to try to calculate the pixel per meter.